# Login de usuarios con flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, aplicación-web, flask

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en flask, pero no logro hacer el modulo de login, al hacer la consulta no encuentra coincidencias y salta hacia el else e imprime "usuario no encontrado".

¿Alguien me puede hacer que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    if request.method == "POST":
       username = request.form.get("username")
       password = request.form.get("password")

    query = db.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = :username and password = :password", {
                     "username": username, "password": password}).fetchall()    

    if query == 1:

        session["id"] = query.id
        session['usuario'] = query.username              
        message = Markup(
            """<p class="alert alert-success text-center font-weight-bold">Log in Successful!</p>""")
        print("ID : "+session['id']+"\n USER :"+ session['usuaruio'])
        return redirect(url_for('cpanel', message))

    else :
        message = Markup(
            """<p class="alert alert-danger text-center font-weight-bold">User no Found!</p>""")

return render_template("/index.html",message=message)
```

Comment: creo que deberias validar con query.rowCount >1

Comment: No puedes depurar los valores del login para imprimirlos por pantalla y ver que son correctos (el que pones en el login comparado con la bd) ?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba mejor con esto ami me funciono cuando tuve el mismo problema

```
if query is not None:
            el resto de tu codigo
```